# How to render json and at the same time refresh a partial using AJAX (Rails)

Tags: ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller action (lets call it some_controller_action) that needs to render out some json (for the javascript to pick up) and at the same time refresh/re-render a partial using some_controller_action.js.erb.

My code suggestion is something like this:

```
def some_controller_action

  #
  # lots of code here
  #

  respond_to do |format|
    render :json => {:something => something}, :status => :ok
    format.html {
      redirect_to somewhere
    }
    format.js
  end
end
```

The client side ajax/javascript triggers this action and receives the json as response. It looks like this:

```
someCoffeescripAction = ->
  $.ajax
    type: "post"
    dataType: "json"
    data:
      some_data_name: some_data_content
    url: "some_url/some_controller_action"
    success: (data, status, xhr) ->
      do_something_with_the_response(data)

    error: (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
```

Of course this don't work, as I am not allowed to render twice in the same action. But then what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your javascript looks like? Do you fetch the controller action by ajax? If so, then you just have to wait until the ajax call is done, and then trigger a re-render of your partial, either by using the just fetched json data, or by calling another ajax function.

Comment: Hi. Yes, AJAX in the javasript is fetching the controller action. I have updated my post to display this.